# The same layout displays no alike in xlarge screen between Android 2.3 and 4.x

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-button

[Update] Thanks Kai, this issue is caused by @dimen/activity_vertical_margin in XML. The default value of dimens.xml is 128dp in values-sw720dp-land. (others are 16dp).

---

I create a new empty project, and run it on Android 4.2 and 2.3 (with Xlarge screen 10.1" WXGA 1280 x 800). Here are the screen capture. Why does "Android 4.x" and "XLARGE" screen cause the content indention?

[image: Android 2.3] (Android 2.3)
[image: Android 4.2] (Android 4.2)

Comment: Is the 'Cancel' button the only thing that's incorrect with your layout? Please show us your xml layout, plus any code for your layout of the dialog box.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `"wrap_content"` or `weight`? Either may help

Comment: Please see the new update for a screen capture of a empty project.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the Xlarge qualifier for `layouts` you also can use version numbers. I'm not sure why it would be different if it is the same resolution and screen size but you can also use version qualifiers for your `layout` folders.

So, you could have one that is in `res/layout-v15` (4.x) and one in `res/layout-xlarge(since its working in 2.3)

This should make devices with 4.x use use the `layout-v15` and anything below with the appropriate screen size would use `layout-xlarge`. I don't know if this will take care of all your problems but it may help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works well in Android 2.3 (with the same layout). I didn't modify anything for Android 4.x. So if I create new res/layout-v15, it will include the same layouts as res/layout-xlarge

Comment: Yes, but you can adjust those layouts to look right with in the 4.3 devices

Comment: Alright I see. But the truth is, even if I put an element that "alignParentLeft", it still indents. Maybe I can try marginLeft="-20dp" ?! It's too weird

Comment: Maybe. But why do you have those `invisible` `View`s there like `fake`. Those are still taking up space. If you don't want them to then you need to change their `visibility` to `gone`

Comment: I have 4 buttons in the Main screen. I just want them to be arranged well. So I use a invisible fake element to be "centerVertical=true" and let other buttons to align to it.

Comment: What happens if you use `wrap_content` for the `width` of your `Button`s?

Comment: Please see the new update for a screen capture of a empty project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very larg marginLeft and marginRight is applied to the 4.x version of the dialog:
[image]

You should check your XML and image resources to see if different margin is applied for different API level.

Comment: Provide all the values that activity_horizontal_margin may take. Also, does your layout look right in the Eclipse layout screen?

Comment: Thank you. The issue is caused by @dimen/activity_vertical_margin, and the default value in values-sw720dp-land is 128dp. (others are 16dp). Thanks again.